# Verificar se há assinaturas ativas com App Billing Android

Tags: android, android-billing

Olá, estou implementando assinaturas em meu app que servirá para remover os anúncios. Tenho uma activity que está realizando as compras e está funcionando.

Quando a compra é finalizada com sucesso eu salvo um código no shared preferences para me informar que há uma assinatura ativa. No entanto me surgiu uma dúvida, como a compra é realizada fora da activity principal, caso o usuário não renove a assinatura quando ela expirar o código salvo no shared preferences sempre vai estar como comprado.

Pensei em fazer uma nova conexão com o Billing na activity principal, assim toda a vez que o aplicativo fosse aberto seria checado se há assinatura ativa e faria um edit no código no shared preferences.

No entanto, fiquei meio confuso no sentido de saber quais partes do código do app billing utilizar para fazer essa checagem.

Como posso fazer essa verificação utilizando o menos possível de código?

Desde já eu agradeço.

Comment: Cada caso é um caso. Salvar somente no sharedpreference talvez não seja mesmo mesmo uma boa opção. Por exemplo em um app como spotify, se eu usar ele no tablet e no celular, eu teria que fazer 2 compras de assinaturas ou somente uma? Acredito que você deve armazenar essa informação externamente para que possa usar em diversos dispositivos. Mas claro, vai depender do seu plano de negócio.

Comment: Salvo se eu estiver enganado, se você compra alguma coisa em um determinado app e quer usar em dois dispositivos, acho que teria que utilizar a mesma conta da play store  em ambos. Obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 1):

tive um caso parecido com isso e fiz assim ó:

```
public class MainActivity ... {
    // ...
    private boolean mIsPremium = false;
    static final String SKU_PREMIUM = "premium";
    private IabHelper mHelper;
    private String payload = "";
    // ...
    void complain(String message) {
        alert("Error: " + message);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        isEmulator = Build.MODEL.contains("google_sdk") || Build.MODEL.contains("Emulator") || Build.MODEL.contains("Android SDK");
        final String BASE64_KEY = "SUA CHAVE PUBLICA BASE_64";
        if (!isEmulator) {
            mHelper = new IabHelper(this, BASE64_KEY);
            mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);
            Log.d(TAG, "Starting setup.");
            mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Setup finished.");
                    if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                        complain("Problem setting up in-app billing: " + result);
                        return;
                    }
                    if (mHelper == null) return;
                    Log.d(TAG, "Setup successful. Querying inventory.");
                    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    // ...
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RC_REQUEST) {
            if (mHelper == null)
                return;
            if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
            }
        }
    }
    // ...
    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");
            if (mHelper == null) return;
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                complain("Failed to query inventory: " + result);
                return;
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");
            Purchase premiumPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_PREMIUM);
            mIsPremium = (premiumPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(premiumPurchase));
            Log.d(TAG, "User is " + (mIsPremium ? "PREMIUM" : "NOT PREMIUM"));
        }
    };

    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: " + purchase);

            if (mHelper == null) return;

            if (result.isFailure()) {
                complain("Error purchasing: " + result);
                return;
            }
            if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
                complain("Error purchasing. Authenticity verification failed.");
                return;
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "Purchase successful.");

            if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_PREMIUM)) {
                // bought the premium upgrade!
                Log.d(TAG, "Purchase is premium upgrade. Congratulating user.");
                alert("Thank you for upgrading to premium!");
                mIsPremium = true;
                // aqui eu passo verdadeiro para a variável mIsPremium uma única vez e somente se o cara pagou mesmo
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
        mHelper = null;
    }
    // ...
    boolean verifyDeveloperPayload(Purchase p) {
        payload = p.getDeveloperPayload();
        return true;
    }
}
```

No meu caso um app que adquire a versão premium, (qual ao seu remover ads), eu apenas verifico se o meu item na loja foi comprado e se sim, passo o valor "true" para a variável mIsPremium, depois quando eu vou chamar qualquer outra activity partindo da minha mainactivity eu passo o valor dessa variável mIsPremium em um Bundle para ler nessa activity que estou chamando.

Por esse metodo voce verifica direto na assinatura do usuário para o app especifico e ele ja faz o controle normalmente, sem precisar gravar isso nas preferences do aparelho.

Espero que resolva para voce, aqui funciona blzura, tirando os usuarios "nós cegos" que sempre dizem que pagaram e os reclamas não sumiram, mas todos sabemos que esses não pagaram nada...

Muita sorte ai

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Vou fazer uns testes aqui e retornarei.